# Overlapping Borders With UICollectionView - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, border, uicollectionviewcell

I just implemented a new collection view into my app, this collectionView requires a border around it or else it would look odd...

My problem is that when I added the border, the border of the cells in the collectionView overlap each other. I tried solving this by just making the darkest color possible so you wouldn't notice the overlap but for some reason the color still goes darker.

This is what the problem looks like:
[image]

And This is how I implemented the border around the cell:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celll", for: indexPath) as! profileLandscapeCollectionViewCell
cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor //trying to get the darkest color (same as UIColor.black.cgColor)
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think it's darker, but thicker. Perhaps increasing the `borderWidth` could fix the issue.

Comment: @JarWarren Yeah, that's what I thought too. But I tried changing the width and I tested it out with different colors to see if it gets darker. Turns out, changing the width doesn't do anything. Thanks!